# ros2-rviz2 environment for crazyflie simulation

Tags: ros, rviz, ros2-launch

I's would like to use rviz2 environment to simulate cf2. I followed the ros2 tutorial in [cf2 ros2 tutorial](https://imrclab.github.io/crazyswarm2/usage.html). However, I have not seen crazyflie structure on rviz. I added the terminal output and rviz output below when I run `ros2 launch crazyflie launch.py backend:=sim`. Could you help us to figure out it, thanks.

**Terminal output:**

```
ntukenmez3@ae-icps-407120:~/Documents/ros2_ws$ ros2 launch crazyflie launch.py backend:=sim
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/ntukenmez3/.ros/log/2023-10-09-16-49-45-223196-ae-icps-407120-1493054
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [crazyflie_server-3]: process started with pid [1493069]
[INFO] [teleop-1]: process started with pid [1493065]
[INFO] [joy_node-2]: process started with pid [1493067]
[INFO] [rviz2-4]: process started with pid [1493071]
[crazyflie_server-3] Traceback (most recent call last):
[crazyflie_server-3]   File "/home/ntukenmez3/Documents/ros2_ws/install/crazyflie_sim/lib/crazyflie_sim/crazyflie_server", line 33, in <module>
[crazyflie_server-3]     sys.exit(load_entry_point('crazyflie-sim==2.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'crazyflie_server')())
[crazyflie_server-3]   File "/home/ntukenmez3/Documents/ros2_ws/install/crazyflie_sim/lib/crazyflie_sim/crazyflie_server", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
[crazyflie_server-3]     return next(matches).load()
[crazyflie_server-3]   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 171, in load
[crazyflie_server-3]     module = import_module(match.group('module'))
[crazyflie_server-3]   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[crazyflie_server-3]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[crazyflie_server-3]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
[crazyflie_server-3]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
[crazyflie_server-3]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[crazyflie_server-3]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
[crazyflie_server-3]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
[crazyflie_server-3]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
[crazyflie_server-3]   File "/home/ntukenmez3/Documents/ros2_ws/install/crazyflie_sim/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/crazyflie_sim/crazyflie_server.py", line 27, in <module>
[crazyflie_server-3]     from .crazyflie_sil import CrazyflieSIL, TrajectoryPolynomialPiece
[crazyflie_server-3]   File "/home/ntukenmez3/Documents/ros2_ws/install/crazyflie_sim/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/crazyflie_sim/crazyflie_sil.py", line 13, in <module>
[crazyflie_server-3]     import cffirmware as firm
[crazyflie_server-3]   File "/home/ntukenmez3/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cffirmware.py", line 15, in <module>
[crazyflie_server-3]     import _cffirmware
[crazyflie_server-3] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffirmware'
[ERROR] [crazyflie_server-3]: process has died [pid 1493069, exit code 1, cmd '/home/ntukenmez3/Documents/ros2_ws/install/crazyflie_sim/lib/crazyflie_sim/crazyflie_server --ros-args -r __node:=crazyflie_server --params-file /tmp/launch_params_tlz3oesf --params-file /tmp/launch_params_ryuo0gtw'].
[teleop-1] [INFO] [1696884585.792142192] [teleop]: Mode changed to cmd_vel_world
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1696884585.938415023] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1696884585.938531612] [rviz2]: OpenGl version: 4.6 (GLSL 4.6)
[rviz2-4] [INFO] [1696884585.970863875] [rviz2]: Stereo is NOT SUPPORTED
```

**rviz output:**

[image]

Comment: This is a very specific question that only the crazyswarm2 or crazyflie people know how to answer. This is already being asked in this discussion https://github.com/IMRCLab/crazyswarm2/discussions/294.

Comment: The problem was solved. The steps [ros2-crazyswarm](https://imrclab.github.io/crazyswarm2/installation.html) are supposed to be followed strictly and carefully from the top of the [python bindings](https://www.bitcraze.io/documentation/repository/crazyflie-firmware/master/building-and-flashing/build/#build-python-bindings) Also, the export statement is need to run and set correctly that is important part (the fifth step in [ros2-crazyswarm](https://imrclab.github.io/crazyswarm2/installation.html)).